# How to close a dialog box automatically when opening a different one in React

Tags: reactjs, dialog, modal-dialog, state

[image: TopButtonsBarComponent]

I am making a react app that has a navbar as pictured above. The navbar is a component called "TopButtonsBar". Rendered inside this TopButtonsBar component are a component for every button picture above. These components from left to right are InfoButton, NotificationsButton, and so on. Each of the button components manage their own state which dictates whether a dialog box of a given button should be shown or not. Here is what the buttons component look like individually, using the InfoButton component as an example.

```
    export default class InfoButton extends React.Component{
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isDialogueOpen:false,
            isHoveringOver:false
        };
        this.handleOpenDialogue = this.handleOpenDialogue.bind(this);
        this.handleHoverOver = this.handleHoverOver.bind(this);
    }
    
    **handleOpenDialogue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            isDialogueOpen:!prevState.isDialogueOpen
        }));
    }**
    handleHoverOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!this.state.isDialogueOpen){
            this.setState((prevState) => ({
                isHoveringOver:!prevState.isHoveringOver
            }));
        }
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="navbar-button">
                <img 
                    onMouseOver={this.handleHoverOver} 
                    onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOver} 
                    onClick={this.handleOpenDialogue}
                    src={this.state.isHoveringOver?infoButtonHovered:infoButtonNotHovered} alt="Info"
                />
                {this.state.isHoveringOver && !this.state.isDialogueOpen && <InfoRollover />}
                **{this.state.isDialogueOpen && <InfoDialogue />}**
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The important bits are * **enclosed by asterisks** *. This logic works fine on a buttons individual level. What I am trying to do is the following: If, as picture above, the message notifications button is selected, if I click on the on the info button, I would like the message notifications button to close, simultaneously as the info button opens. However I have been unsuccessful in conceptualizing how I should re-configure the state. Should the TopButtonsBar component hold the information on the state if any of the buttons are closed? If so, how would I  go about re-approaching how the buttons open (and if an individual button component should control that state or not). Also, I am not using any state manager such as Redux, Hooks, etc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to have the flags (as in `isDialogueOpen`) for all the child components (`InfoButton`, `NotificationButton` and so on) in the parent component's state (`TopButtonsBar`).

#### TopButtonsBar.js

I would start off with adding a few constants identifying each dialogue boxes. After that, we can declare a state, which would point to the diaogue box which is open.

Just follow along the comments in the **code** below to understand better.

```js
// adding some constants here
const INFO_BUTTON = 'INFO_BUTTON';
const NOTIFICATION_BUTTON = 'NOTIFICATION_BUTTON';

export default class TopButtonsBar extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         ...
         // adding this state to point out which dialogue is open
         selectedDialogue: null
      }
   }
   
   handleOpenDialogue = (e, selectedDialogue) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (selectedDialogue === this.state.selectedDialogue) {
         // close dialogue if already open
         this.setState({selectedDialogue: null});
      } else {
         // else open this dialogue
         this.setState({selectedDialogue});
      }
   }
   
   ....
   render() {
      return (
          ....
          <InfoButton
               isDialogueOpen={this.state.selectedDialogue === INFO_BUTTON}
               handleOpenDialogue={(e) => handleOpenDialogue(e, INFO_BUTTON)}
               ...
          />
          <NotificationButton
               isDialogueOpen={this.state.selectedDialogue === NOTIFICATION_BUTTON}
               handleOpenDialogue={(e) => handleOpenDialogue(e, NOTIFICATION_BUTTON)}
               ...
          />
      )
   }
}
```

#### InfoButton.js

Now that we are passing the state and its handling function from the `TopButtonsBar` component as props, we can call them directly in `InfoButton` and `NotificationButton`, without any related local states required.

```js
export default class InfoButton extends React.Component{
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // removing the state from here
            isHoveringOver:false
        };
        this.handleHoverOver = this.handleHoverOver.bind(this);
    }
    
    // removing the handleOpenDialogue function here

    ...
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="navbar-button">
                <img 
                    onMouseOver={this.handleHoverOver} 
                    onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOver}
                    // calling handleOpenDialogue from props
                    onClick={this.props.handleOpenDialogue}
                    ...
                />
                // using isDialogueOpen from props now
                {this.state.isHoveringOver && !this.props.isDialogueOpen && <InfoRollover />}
                {this.props.isDialogueOpen && <InfoDialogue />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```